# is it possible to execute QueryAll() using Bulk API

Tags: bulk-api

We are trying to get deleted records via bulk API, is it possible. I am already aware that with SOAP API this is possible, but if we need to handle large volume of data Bulk should have this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get deleted records via Bulk API, you need to use SOAP API.

Update: this was not possible in April 2014, but as of now its possible using BULK API.

Comment: Incorrect - see DavidSchach's answer below...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Thank you to @User6704 for showing that I was wrong. Bulk API can be used to export data:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm

Comment: you can query using bulk api - please find here is the doc - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_bulk_query.htm

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Bulk Query API gives more records in one batch (10,000) it has retry mechanism and its async and its very fast.